# Converting Classes All at Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have four classes `show`,`hide1`,`hide2`, and `hide3`. I want to change each of these classes and replace it with the one next to it. In other words, my jQuery code looks like this...

```
$(".show").removeClass("show").addClass("hide1");
$(".hide1").removeClass("hide1").addClass("hide2");
$(".hide2").removeClass("hide2").addClass("hide3");
$(".hide3").removeClass("hide3").addClass("show");
```

The problem is that the four classes end up all having the show class which is not what I want. I just want the classes of show to convert to hide1, hide1 convert into hide2, etc. How could I write the code so that those four lines all happen at once, instead of one at a time?

Comment: I understand the question, but why dont you just remove the first and add the last class hideX? Whats your motivation?

Comment: just out of curiosity, you want that to happen on click... by clicking some button or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select each group first, then alter:

```
// read
var $show = $('.show');
var $hide1 = $('.hide1');
var $hide2 = $('.hide2');
var $hide3 = $('.hide3');

// write
$show.removeClass('show').addClass('hide1');
$hide1.removeClass('hide1').addClass('hide2');
$hide2.removeClass('hide2').addClass('hide3');
$hide3.removeClass('hide3').addClass('show');
```

Comment: It works but... yuk. This code is far from DRY (no offense to the answerer, it’s correct after all)

Comment: I like non-DRY code when trying to learn something. DRYing it up is for something when you are refactoring your code.

Comment: @David agreed. I wanted to convey the separation more than anything else; I was willing to gamble that [someone else would show something fancy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13504047/139010);

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way,

```
function circulateClass(c){
    var i, cl=[];
    for(i=0;i<c.length;i++)
        cl[c[i]]=$("."+c[i]);

    for(i=0;i<c.length;i++)
        cl[c[i]].removeClass(c[i]).addClass(c[(i+1)%c.length]));
}

circulateClass(["show","hide1", "hide2", "hide3"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you save the classes in an array like this:

```
var classes = ['show','hide1','hide2','hide3'];
```

You can do fancy stuff like this:

```
$('.'+classes.join(',.')).attr('class', function(i) {
   return classes[i+1] || classes[0];
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7DuEV/

Comment: I’m just used to splitting strings for smaller footprints, I probably shouldn’t do that when writing clear answers though... correcting.

Comment: I was just kidding, but nice edit any way. For beginners this one will be more appropriate, that's for sure.

Comment: How about `return classes[(i+1) % classes.length]` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order...

```
$(".show").removeClass("show").addClass("hide1");
$(".hide3").removeClass("hide3").addClass("show");
$(".hide2").removeClass("hide2").addClass("hide3");
```

And for the last one, filter by the class name:

```
$(".hide1").filter(function(){
    return !$(this).hasClass('show');
}).removeClass("hide1").addClass("hide2");
```

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/atufiz/1/edit)*

```
c = 0; // zero based index n (set initial one)

var $el = $( '#parent' ).find( 'div' );
$el.hide().eq( c ).show();

$( '#button' ).click( function() {
   $el.hide().eq( ++c % $el.length ).show(); 
});
```